# Getting the shape of the array from a PKL file

Tags: python, arrays, joblib

I have this machine learning model that I have saved into a PKL file. In "MC_features" you can see that I have assigned the 21 values in the model to be 0 by default. I am trying to see if there is a way to get the shape of the array from the PKL file so I would not need to manually change the "21" and it will automatically register it from the shape or the number of elements in array.

This is how I saved the PKL file.

```
Dtree = LinearRegression()
Dtree.fit(X_train, y_train)

import joblib
joblib.dump(Dtree,'MC_Model.pkl')
```

This is my flask code.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import numpy as np
import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)
model = joblib.load('MC_Model.pkl')

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    # default values for `GET`
    cluster = None
    material = None
    MC_features = [np.zeros((21,), dtype=int)]
    MC_text = 'Usage Amount: ???'
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cluster = request.form.get('cluster')
        print('cluster:', cluster)
        
        material = request.form.get('material')
        print('material:', material)
                  
        if cluster:
            index = int(cluster)
            MC_features[0][index] = 1.0

        if material:
            index = int(material)
            MC_features[0][index] = 1.0

        print(MC_features)
        
        MC_prediction = model.predict(MC_features)
        #prediction = [np.random.randint(0, 100)]
        
        MC_text = 'Usage Amount: {}'.format(MC_prediction[0])
                
    return render_template('BOM.html',MC_prediction=MC_text, MC_features=MC_features[0], cluster=cluster, material=material)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue.
i just found it today

```
model.feature_names_in_
```

reference:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html?highlight=linearregression#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31819712)